# GapSort or ShellSort not swaping properly

Tags: c, sorting

I'm setting up a GapSort program, for some arrays code isn't working. What am I missing?

```
void main()
{
    int eX[10] = {1, 3, 49, 29, 20, 8, 28, 24, 10, 29};
    int eXlen = sizeof(eX) / sizeof(int);
    gapSort(eX, eXlen);
} 
void gapSort(int arr[], int len)
    {
        int temp, gap, swap;
        gap = len / 2;
        while (1)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < len - gap; i++)
            {
                swap = 0;
                if (arr[i] > arr[i + gap])
                {
                    temp = arr[i];
                    arr[i] = arr[i + gap];
                    arr[i + gap] = temp;
                    swap = 1;
                }
            }
            if (swap == 0)
            {
                if (gap == 1)
                    break;
                gap /= 2;
            }
        }
    }
```

1, 3, 49, 29, 20, 8, 28, 24, 10, 29 for this type of array it isn't working

Comment: I used an array generator but I used this array because this sort isn't working for this specific array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to put `swap = 0;` before the `for` loop.

You want to change the `gap` value if you have not swapped anything in the complete cycle. With your current implementation you might have swapped values e.g. with `i=1`, but you will reset `swap=0` on the next loop, so you will re-iterate with the same `gap` only if you swapped the values for the last value of `i`. You might have seen the problem yourself if you would have shown the value of `swap` next to `arrDisp`. (I assume `arrDisp` is a function to display the array contents. This function call was in the original question before it has been edited.)

```
static void gapSort(int arr[], int len)
{
    int temp, gap, swap;
    gap = len / 2;
    while (1)
    {
        swap = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < len - gap; i++)
        {
            if (arr[i] > arr[i + gap])
            {
                temp = arr[i];
                arr[i] = arr[i + gap];
                arr[i + gap] = temp;
                swap = 1;
            }
        }
        /* arrDisp(arr, len); */
        if (swap == 0)
        {
            if (gap == 1)
                break;
            gap /= 2;
        }
    }
}
```